# The convergence of sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

i'd like to show that $a_n=-\ln(n)+$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}  {{1}\over {k}} $ converges to some $\alpha$ $\in$$[0,1]$

I found that the sequence monotone decreasing sequence, by mathematics induction.

So i'd like to show that the sequence $a_n$$\in$$[0,1]$, for concluding above statement.

But I'm stuck here. How can I show that?
I tried to $a_n$ is monotone decreasing and $a_1$=1, $a_n$$\in$$(-$infinity$,1]$ but i can't find how to show that it is more than equal to 0 ..

Comment: Have a look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant . For more information search for _Euler Maclaurin  formula_.

Comment: @Jens Schwaiger it is the same sequence,, but there is not information i want..

Comment: Note that $0< \gamma<1.$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

Consider the map $f(n)=1/n$ on $[1,n]$
Then,

$\int_1^n f(n)\,dn$$\leq$$1+1/2+1/3+....+1/n$.

( This can be seen from, upper sum is greater than or equal to actual area under the curve.)

Hope you can follow from here.